# Need help for shell script to copy multiple dir and packing into tar

Tags: linux, shell, tar

Im amateur in script shell so i need help for shell cripting for my issue :

i have 2 directory inside this path /home/backup :
CSC
DFG

and each folder (CSC & DFG) have a these dir inside  : weekly and monthly

and i want to copy all files and packing into 1 file .tar inside weekly dir > into monthly dir

so my question :
hows the script for this my issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to create a tar file, here is the command (with verbose):

```
tar -cvf backup.tar /home/backup/*
```

and then if you need to compress it, which I assume you want to do:

```
gzip backup.tar
```